# $match and $ne aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently trying to exclude a specific date from my mongodb collection through aggregation. However, I am unable to do it for some reason.

Here is my aggregate function:

```
collection.aggregate([
{$match:{$ne:[moment(value, 'M-DD-YYYY').startOf('day').toDate(), moment(value, 'M-DD-YYYY').endOf('day').toDate() ]}}])
```

value is the date: '7-17-2018'

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the logic of the [comparison operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) in the date range query and use the logical [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator to query the complement of the date range i.e.

```
const momentObj = moment(value, 'M-DD-YYYY');
const start = momentObj.startOf('day').toDate(); 
const end   = momentObj.endOf('day').toDate();

collection.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
        '$or': [
            { 'invoiceDate': { '$lt': start } },
            { 'invoiceDate': { '$gt': end   } }
        ]
    } } 
], (err, data) => console.log(data))
```

Comment: I think that should be `$or`'ed, not `$and`'ed...?!